# Reference a button created in constructor from Controller on Sencha Touch 2?

Tags: model-view-controller, constructor, sencha-touch-2

I've been researching on how to reference methods of a button using MVC on Sencha Touch, but none of the articles has worked fine for me since I declare all my controls on the constructor of my views.

Here is an example of my code:

```
Ext.define('TPTMOBILE.view.Login',{
    extend: 'Ext.Panel',
    ...
    config: {
        ...
    },

    constructor: function(){
        var submitButton = Ext.create('Ext.Button', {
            text: 'Login'
        });
    }

});
```

So I'd like to know how to reference the onTap method of my 'submiButton' button.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your constructor method will not working, try this instead:

```
constructor: function(config){
    this.callParent(config);
    this.add(
        {
            xtype: "button",
            text: 'Login',
            action: 'doTap'
        }
    );
}
```

Your `constructor` method must contain a call to `callParent` in order to pass the config object to the parent constructor otherwise it won't work.

After that, you have several ways to achieve your `onTap` method on the button but since you want to use MVC on Sencha Touch so you can set an action for the button

```
action: 'doTap'
```

Then in your controller you can do as following to run your code when tapping on that button:

```
refs: {
    doTap: 'button[action=doTap]'
},

control: {
    doTap: {
        tap: 'doTap'
    },
},

doTap: function() {
    alert('doTap function activvated');
}
```

Hope it helps :)